# SASS conditional statement that contains

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a `@mixin` for border-radius.  This is what I have so far and it works:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius,$tb:"",$lr:"") {
@if $lr=="both" and $tb=="both"{
      -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
         -moz-border-radius: $radius;
          -ms-border-radius: $radius;
           -o-border-radius: $radius;
              border-radius: $radius;
} @else {   
    @if ($lr~="l"){}
    @if ($lr=="r" or $lr=="") and ($tb=="t" or $tb==""){
          -ms-border-top-right-radius: $radius;
              border-top-right-radius: $radius;
    }
    @if ($lr=="r" or $lr=="") and ($tb=="b" or $tb==""){
       -ms-border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
           border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
    }
    @if ($lr=="l" or $lr=="") and ($tb=="t" or $tb==""){
           -ms-border-top-left-radius: $radius;
               border-top-left-radius: $radius;
    }
    @if ($lr=="l" or $lr=="") and ($tb=="b" or $tb==""){
        -ms-border-bottom-left-radius: $radius;
            border-bottom-left-radius: $radius;
    }
}
}
```

I call it like this `@include border-radius(5px,"b","r");` that will render the browser specific border-radius for bottom right.

I would like to simplify it even more and call it like this `@include border-radius(5px,"br");` but to make that work, I need to know how to test if the variable `contains`.

The css selector `$tb~="t"` doesn't work.  How do I check to see if the variable contains a value?

**UPDATE**
Ideally, the solution would look something like this:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius,$sides...) {
$t:0;$b:0;$r:0;$l:0;
@if $sides ~="l" {$l:1;}
@if $sides ~="r" {$r:1;}
@if $sides ~="t" {$t:1;}
@if $sides ~="b" {$b:1;}
@if $l+$r==0 {$l:1;$r:1;}//if neither l nor r are passed, both are included
@if $t+$b==0 {$t:1;$b:1;}//if neither b nor t are passed, both are included
@if $sides=="" or $t+$b+$r+$l==4 {//handle case when all are returned
      -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
         -moz-border-radius: $radius;
          -ms-border-radius: $radius;
           -o-border-radius: $radius;
              border-radius: $radius;
} @else {
    @if $r==1 and $t==1{
          -ms-border-top-right-radius: $radius;
              border-top-right-radius: $radius;
    }
    @if $r==1 and $b==1{
       -ms-border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
           border-bottom-right-radius: $radius;
    }
    @if $l==1 and $t==1{
           -ms-border-top-left-radius: $radius;
               border-top-left-radius: $radius;
    }
    @if $l==1 and $b==1{
        -ms-border-bottom-left-radius: $radius;
            border-bottom-left-radius: $radius;
    }
}}
```

Then, adding `@include border-radius(3px,l,t,b);` & `@include border-radius(3px,l);` would return:

```
-ms-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-ms-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
```

and `@include border-radius(3px);` would return:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
     -o-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
```

Given that none of the calculation happens at runtime, I am not concerned about performance, but I am concerned that my sass code is concise and easy to read.  I think I can make the `@each` approach work.

Comment: IE and Opera have *never* had a prefix for border-radius:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: @cimmanon, I was unaware of that site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how to do a contains, but you could pass a list and use @each to cycle through.

```
$sides: l,b,r,t

@each $side in $sides{
    @if $side==l {do something}
    @else if $side==t {do something}
    @else if $side==b {do something}
    @else if $side==r {do something}
}
```

It isn't as convenient as contains, but should let you execute code if the list has the value.

Comment: How would I use @each to check for a t,l,r,b?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to be too clever.  The most straight forward way is to name it *exactly* after the property name.

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}

@mixin border-top-right-radius($r) {
    // other prefixes
    border-top-right-radius: $r;
}
```

If you still really want clever, this will do:

```
@mixin border-radius($tl: null, $tr: null, $br: null, $bl: null) {
    border-top-left-radius: $tl;
    border-top-right-radius: $tr;
    border-bottom-right-radius: $br;
    border-bottom-left-radius: $bl;
}

.foo {
    @include border-radius($tl: .5em, $br: .5em);
}
```

Generates:

```
.foo {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

Just keep in mind that writing out the individual properties that way is by far more output than using the shorthand, so use responsibly:

```
.foo {
    border-radius: .5em 0;
}
```

Comment: I take it then that contains isn't an options with sass?  If I am going to go with the straightforward, I might as well just type it into the css.  I was hoping to create a single mixin that would let me easily configure for all options.

Comment: No, the tilde is not an operator available in Sass.